# Prisma js ORM - how to filter for results that have entry in a related table (effectively JOIN)?

Tags: javascript, orm, prisma

I have 2 tables:

```
model Collection {
    id                String                 @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid/
    floorPrices       CollectionFloorPrice[]
}

model CollectionFloorPrice {
    id           String     @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
    collection   Collection @relation(fields: [collectionId], references: [id])
    collectionId String     @db.Uuid
}
```

How do I query collections that only have rows present in `CollectionFloorPrice`? In SQL it would be a simple JOIN.

This isn't working:

```
    return await this.prisma.collection.findMany({
      where: {
        floorPrices: {
          exists: true,
        },
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prisma's relation filters for a model named `CollectionFloorPrice` are:

```
export type CollectionFloorPriceFilter = {
  every?: CollectionFloorPriceWhereInput | null
  some?: CollectionFloorPriceWhereInput | null
  none?: CollectionFloorPriceWhereInput | null
}
```

To get only `Collection`s that have at least one `CollectionFloorPrice`, you should use `some` (instead of `exists`) and specify a condition that always return true for any related record that exists.

And if you want to your query includes related `CollectionFloorPrice`s you must specify it in `include` property.

```
 return await this.prisma.collection.findMany({
   where: {
     floorPrices: {
       some: {
         id: { not: "" } // It always should be true.
       },
     },
   },
   
   // if you want to include related floor prices in returned object:
   include: {
     floorPrices: true,
   },
 });
```

Comment: From https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/2772#discussioncomment-1712222:

to find records that have a relation
`where: {relation: { isNot: null }}`

to find records that don't have a relation
`where: { relation: { is: null }}`

(based on @Ryan comment)

Answer (score 5):

```
      prisma.collection.findMany({
        where: { floorPrices: { some: {} } }
      })
```

Comment: this is the actual working answer

Comment: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/2772#discussioncomment-1712222 is helpful.  https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting wasn't clear.