# Query many-to-many relationship in Prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I want to query a many-to-many relation in prisma, like "select all posts where the category ID equals 'abc...' ".

This seems fairly simple but even after spending 2 hours reading the [Prisma docs on relational queries](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries), I can't figure it out.

```
model Category {
  id               String    @id @default(cuid())
  name             String
  post             Post[]
}

model Post {
  id               String    @id @default(cuid())
  body             String
  category         Category[]
}
```

```
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
      select: { 
        category: {
          where: {id: "abc123"}
        }},
    });
```

this returns an array of as many category objects as there are posts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500284/prisma-js-orm-how-to-filter-for-results-that-have-entry-in-a-related-table-ef#comment134680144_74122680

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return all posts which have the category of id `abc123`. Note that posts may include categories other than id `abc123`.

```js
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: {
        category: {
            some: {
                id: 'abc123',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

`some`: Returns all records where one or more ("some") related records match filtering criteria.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#some