# Prisma Client Select query on existence of value in joined table via Schema

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, prisma

In my instance i have a schema joining bonuses to a casino.  query works great for data but I am unable to filter via the query itself.  The where clause I used appears to be correct but I get an error the stating  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nodeposit' does not exist in type.  But I can query that data.

```
const data = await prisma.casino_p_casinos.findMany({
where: { 
  approved: 1, 
  rogue: 0,
  bonuses: {
    nodeposit: { gt : 0 },
  }
 },
select: {
  id: true,
  clean_name: true,
  casino: true,
  button: true,
  bonuses: {
    where: {
      nodeposit: { gt: 0 },
    },
  },
},

take: 14,
```

});

If I remove the bonus pard in the WHERE clause the query works as expected but I want to grab all bonuses for each casino, but only if the bonuses contains a nodeposit value.

This nis what I want to use.

```
    const data = await prisma.casino_p_casinos.findMany({
where: { 
  approved: 1, 
  rogue: 0,
  bonuses: {
    nodeposit: { gt : 0 },
  },
 },
select: {
  id: true,
  clean_name: true,
  casino: true,
  button: true,
  bonuses: true,
},

take: 14,
```

});

SCHEMA :

```
model casino_p_casinos {
  id            Int                             @id @default(autoincrement())
  casino        String?
  type          String?
  url           String?
  bonuses       casino_p_bonus[]

model casino_p_bonus {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  parent           Int
  game             String?
  freespins        Int?
  freeplay         String?
  nodeposit        Int?
  deposit          Int?
 
  casino_p_casinos casino_p_casinos @relation(fields: [parent], references: [id])
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500284/prisma-js-orm-how-to-filter-for-results-that-have-entry-in-a-related-table-ef#comment134680144_74122680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a one to many relation, so when you add a where clause, you have one more layer with `some`, `every` or `none` like

```js
const data = await prisma.casino_p_casinos.findMany({
      where: {
        approved: 1,
        rogue: 0,
        bonuses: {
          // 'some' can be replaced by 'every' or 'none' here
          some: {
            nodeposit: { gt: 0 }
          }
        }
      },
      select: {
        id: true,
        clean_name: true,
        casino: true,
        button: true,
        bonuses: true
      },
      take: 14
    })
```

This query will filter `casinos` where some `nodeposit` are greater than 0 and return all bonuses, even those who are equals to 0.

And then, if you only want `bonuses` with `nodeposit` greater than 0 in casinos that have some, you should do:

```js
const data = await prisma.casino_p_casinos.findMany({
      where: {
        approved: 1,
        rogue: 0,
        bonuses: {
          // 'some' can be replaced by 'every' or 'none' here
          some: {
            nodeposit: { gt: 0 }
          }
        }
      },
      select: {
        id: true,
        clean_name: true,
        casino: true,
        button: true,
        bonuses: {
          where: {
            nodeposit: { gt: 0 }
          }
        }
      },
      take: 14
    })
```

Comment: Will add schema to org post

Comment: Sorry, I will get these points, but I just wanted to help him on a language that is not used by everyone
But thanks for the post, I will read it tomorrow!

Comment: Thank you @pompedup that was the exact solution I was searching for,, and thanks for the every / none as well.